# ¿Cómo desactivar stepwizard button de formulario HTML con jquery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy creando un Wizard basado en este ejemplo:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/yaZa

Pero necesito desactivar los botones del menú para que solo funcionen los botones de abajo "Siguiente" y "Finalizar"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté de todo en Jquery, pero si agrego algo me deja de funcionar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
            allWells = $('.setup-content'),
            allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $item = $(this);

        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-primary');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function(){
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
            <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
            <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
            <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form role="form">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 1</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 2</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 3</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas que se muestren inactivos, o que se desactiven en respuesta a algún evento? En el primer caso simplemente agrega el atributo disabled a los anchors (`<a disabled="disabled" ...>`) en el segundo ponles una clase para usarla como selector de conjunto y en el controlador de evento les asignas el atributo mediante `$(selector).prop('disabled', 'disabled');` puedes usar attr en lugar de prop si lo prefieres.

Comment: @quevedo Intenté con la primera opción, no funcionó (<a disabled="disabled" href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-fix" disabled="disabled">2</a>), intenté de esta manera la segunda opción ($('.stepwizard-step a').prop('disabled', 'disabled'); ) tampoco funciona.

Comment: @quevedo Tammbién intenté con esto ($('.stepwizard-step a').unbind('click');), y si funcionó, el problema es que también dejan de funcionar los botones de "siguiente".

Comment: El boton next toma como referencia al elemento a, por lo que si deshabilitas lo de arriba tienes que independizar lo de abajo.

Comment: @AngeReyna Si, por ese motivo me deja de funcionar. ¿Alguna sugerencia por favor? :/

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas, pero básicamente lo que tienes que evitar es que esos botones sean un enlace.

En lugar de esto:

```
 <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
```

Puedes poner esto:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</button>
```

O directamente eliminas ese link y te queda sólo el texto step 1 step 2 ...

Comment: No me funciona, ya lo había intentado pero jquery utiliza esa estructura para contabilizar cuantos pasos tiene el asistente y mostrar el contenido.